# Change working directory in Haskell's GHCi to a path with spaces

Tags: haskell, ghci, working-directory

I am running WinGHCi 1.0.6

I need to change working directory. Here is what I tried:

```
Prelude> :cd "C:/Temp Temp/Temp"
```

Returned error:

```
Exception: SetCurrentDirectory "\"C:/Temp Temp/Temp\"": invalid argument (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)
```

I also tried with single quote, but got the following error:

```
*** Exception: SetCurrentDirectory "'C:/Temp Temp/Temp'": invalid argument (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with no quotes at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system, it appears that using quotes always fails, but using no quotes at all seems to work. (Even for paths with spaces.)

Also seems to work both with forward slashes and backslashes. (Which isn't too surprising... Windows actually accepts either just fine.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Just in case how can I load file with spaces in its name? `Prelude> :l simple file.hs`

Comment: You should also be able to use tab completion for file loads (i.e. `:l simp<tab>`).